# why is Socket.io is very slow on windows?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I recently noticed that Socket.io has become really really slow on windows. I noticed this when I opened two tabs and tried emitting events. It took more than 15 seconds to receive a response from server. Server Coded on NodeJS.

```
Environment:
Windows 10 Pro
Electron Socket.io-Tester
Socket.io - Version 2.0.4
```

Comment: Something is not working correctly in your socket.io implementation/configuration as that is not normal and not something specific to Windows either.  Are you 100% sure that you have exactly the same socket.io version on both client and server?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having this exact problem.  Used to work fine on Windows (and still does on MacOS), now emits are just getting lost in lag, as much as 5 seconds.  This only happens when a 2nd or more connection has been made to the server - as I'm developing a multi player game this is pretty important.  The emit event works fine and you can see it in the frame, its just taking forever for the server to respond.

After much experimentation, I can safely conclude this is a problem with NodeJS LTS itself.  THIS IS WORKING IN v6.13.1, but not for later versions (not sure where it starts, and not going to bother incrementally upgrading Node).

Downgrade node to safely address this issue.  Fun.

Comment: Downgrading to v6.13.1 didn't worked for me on windows 10. Don't know what i'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code are there any proxies? That can sometimes muddle things up a bit.

If there are proxies I found a gist related to a "Socket is slow issue" that was due to proxies. This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mhseiden/2347637) was a "Fix" to the issue maybe it will help. This snippet is the proxy config.

```
    var server = http_m.createServer(function(req, res) {   
    switch(req.headers.host) {
    case "ws.app.com":
        handle_ws(req, res);
        break;
    case "api.app.com":
        handle_api(req, res);
        break;
    default:
        handle_error(req, res);
        break;
    }
});

server.on("upgrade", handle_ws_upgrade);
server.listen(80);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment and nope. There are no proxies. I am testing this on localhost without any proxy.

Comment: Could be related to the fact multiple tabs cause multiple socket connections. They sort of highlight problems and workarounds with the multiple connections from opening multiple tabs using socket.io in this issue thread. https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/628